# Screen on Dell Latitude D520 is darker than normal

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dell-latitude

I think that the screen on my Dell Latitude D520 looks a little darker than normal. I've tried to set the screen to the maximum brightness with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.

Is there another way to make the screen brighter? I have Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on your video adapter, you should be able to adjust brightness (gamma) and colours in the advanced display settings.

if the driver doesn't provide such a facility, use **[PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)** (shareware, $29, try before you buy).